# Annoying error message

Tags: bug, status-norepro

I keep getting the error message "File failed to load: http://math. ... /Main.js" from time to time. Then it takes about 30 seconds or more, and everything is fine.

Does anyone know this problem? What can I do about it?

Comment: Try holding 'Shift' and Refresh the page?

Comment: That doesn't work. During the period I described my browser doesn't react. (I use Firefox and Ubuntu.)

Comment: What version of Firefox and Ubuntu are you are using?

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04.1 and Firefox 3.6.8.

Comment: I had the same problem (it was my first visit to the site) and forcing the browser to reload the start page worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Other than intermittent network connectivity issues, I can't think of any reason this would be happening.